# document.write() JavaScript for Output

Tags: javascript, arrays, function, object

I am using an array of objects.

```
let items = [
    {
        type: "Shirt",
        gender: ["Men", "Women", "Boys", "Girls"],
        size: "Small",

    },
    {
        type: "Shirt",
        gender: ["Men", "Women", "Boys"],
        size: "Medium",

    },
    {
        type: "Shirt",
        gender: ["Men", "Women"],
        size: "Large",

    },
];

let filteredArr = [];
filteredArr = items;
```

I'm searching for a `'Shirt'` with input `let searchForType = "Shirt";` with the following code.

```
function fetchItemsByType() {
    
    let isItemAva = filteredArr.filter(obj => obj["type"] === searchForType);
    isItemAva.forEach(obj => {
        for (let i = 0; i < obj["type"].length; i++) {
            if (obj["type"] === searchForType) {}
        } document.write(obj["type"] + " of " + obj["size"] + " size is Available for " + obj["gender"] + "<br>" + "<br>")
       
    });
    return isItemAva;
}
let getItemsByType = fetchItemsByType();

if (searchForType === searchForType) {
    console.log(getItemsByType);
}
```

Output

```
Shirt of Small size is Available for Men,Women,Boys,Girls

Shirt of Medium size is Available for Men,Women,Boys

Shirt of Large size is Available for Men,Women
```

Then I searched for 'Size' with input `let searchForSize = "Small";` (Note: Both `'Shirt'` and `'Small'` is entered like)

```
let searchForType = "Shirt";
let searchForSize = "Small";
```

And code is:

```
function fetchItemsBySize() {

    let isSizeAva = getItemsByType.filter(obj => obj["size"] === searchForSize);
    isSizeAva.forEach(obj => {
        for (let i = 0; i < obj["size"].length; i++) {
            if (obj["size"] === searchForSize) {}
        }document.write(obj["type"] + " of " + obj["size"] + " size is Available for " + obj["gender"] + "<br>" + "<br>")
    
    });
    return isSizeAva;
}
let getItemsBySize = fetchItemsBySize();

if (searchForSize === searchForSize) {
    console.log(getItemsBySize);
}
```

Output

```
Shirt of Small size is Available for Men,Women,Boys,Girls

Shirt of Medium size is Available for Men,Women,Boys

Shirt of Large size is Available for Men,Women

Shirt of Small size is Available for Men,Women,Boys,Girls
```

All I want to display only

```
Shirt of Small size is Available for Men,Women,Boys,Girls
```

Because I'm looking for a `Shirt` of `Small` size and should get only

```
Shirt of Small size is Available for Men,Women,Boys,Girls
```

So how can I get the result(s) specific only when I entered both `type` and `size` by removing the other results of `Shirts` from my final output.

Answer (score 1):

Don't use document.write

Also

```
if (searchForSize === searchForSize) {
```

is not useful

You have a loop and `if (obj["size"] === searchForSize) {}` which does nothing inside that loop .

Your code would work better with filter and map

I have chose to NOT use default parameters since you seems to be more comfortable setting the 3 parameters by "hand"

```js
let items = [
{ type: "Shirt", gender: ["Men", "Women", "Boys", "Girls"], size: "Small", }, 
{ type: "Shirt", gender: ["Men", "Women", "Boys"], size: "Medium", }, 
{ type: "Shirt", gender: ["Men", "Women"], size: "Large", }, ];

let searchForType ="", searchForSize = "", searchForGender = "";
const getItems = () => items
  .filter(({type,size,gender}) => 
  (searchForType === "" || type === searchForType) && 
  (searchForSize === "" || size === searchForSize) &&
  (searchForGender === "" || gender.includes(searchForGender)) )
  .map(({type,size,gender}) => `${type} of ${size} size is Available for ${searchForGender?gender.filter(gender => gender === searchForGender) : gender.join(", ")}`)
  .join("<br/></br/>");

// type, size and gender are blank
searchForType   = "";
searchForSize   = "";
searchForGender = "";

document.getElementById("output").innerHTML  = "All types:<br/>"
document.getElementById("output").innerHTML += getItems();

searchForType ="Shirt"; // all shirts
document.getElementById("output").innerHTML += "<hr/>All Shirts:<br/>"
document.getElementById("output").innerHTML += getItems();

searchForSize ="Medium"; // Medium shirts
document.getElementById("output").innerHTML += "<hr/>All Medium:<br/>"
document.getElementById("output").innerHTML += getItems();

   // All Men's shirts 
searchForSize =""; // reset size
searchForGender = "Men"; 
document.getElementById("output").innerHTML += "<hr/>All Men:<br/>"
document.getElementById("output").innerHTML += getItems();

// Women's shirts  
searchForGender = "Women"
document.getElementById("output").innerHTML += "<hr/>All women's shirts:<br/>"
document.getElementById("output").innerHTML += getItems();

// All medium girl's shirts
searchForType ="Shirt"; 
searchForGender = "Girls";
searchForSize ="Medium"; 
document.getElementById("output").innerHTML += "<hr/>All medium girls's shirts:<br/>"
document.getElementById("output").innerHTML += getItems() || "None found"; // optional error message can be used in all calls
```

```html
<div id="output"></div>
```

Comment: Can I get result(s) of 'Shirt' only using the code above? If so, where do I need to make changes? @mplungjan

Comment: mplungjan- I want to set my code in a way that when I enter only `searchForType = 'Shirt'` then result(s) of all available `Shirt(s)` should be seen. Next, when I enter `searchForSize = 'Small'` with `searchForType = 'Shirt'` then result(s) of all available shirt(s) with `Small` size should be seen. I hope I'm clear with my query.  Can you help me for the same?

Comment: Ok, I have included all options now. Hope that helps

Answer (score 0):

If you can use filter and map functions you can easily get the values as you wanted, instead of using a `forEach` function, best practice is using map function.

I highly recommend for you to test this out. You will earn lots of time...

```
let filteredArr = [];
const searchForSize = prompt("Enter a size value");
const findItemsWithSize = () => {
    filteredArr = items.filter(fItem => fItem.size === searchForSize).map(item => 
        console.log(item.type + " of " + item.size + " size is Available for " + item.gender.join(" "))
    )
}
if (searchForSize === "Small") {
    findItemsWithSize()
}
```

Faruk

Comment: Did you see my answer at all?

Comment: You are not looking for items

Comment: @mplungjan are you here to make your day some kind of meaningful? :D

Comment: @Faruk for size "Small" I want to filter `getItemsByType` not `filteredArr`. I want to use `filteredArr` for `Shirt` and `getItemsByType` for  size `Small`. Can you please explain both cases seprately. Thanks in advance.